# Auto Resize Font to fit rectangle

Tags: c#, .net, fonts

How can I create in .NET 4.5 / C# a font with a adaptive size to fit a specified rectangle ?

I have a resize based on the string length, the longer the string, the smaller the fontsize, but it does not work very well, if the string is too long the text gets very small. The problem with this method is that if I change the rectangle size all the font sizes are not good again.

Comment: Did you tried anything? Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: Now I have a resize based on the string length, the longer the string, the smaller the fontsize, but it does not work very well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With [Graphics.MeasureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb.aspx) you can measure the size of a string, so you can calculate what you need.

Sample from MSDN

```
private void MeasureStringMin(PaintEventArgs e)
{

    // Set up string. 
    string measureString = "Measure String";
    Font stringFont = new Font("Arial", 16);

    // Measure string.
    SizeF stringSize = new SizeF();
    stringSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(measureString, stringFont);

    // Draw rectangle representing size of string.
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Red, 1), 0.0F, 0.0F, stringSize.Width, stringSize.Height);

    // Draw string to screen.
    e.Graphics.DrawString(measureString, stringFont, Brushes.Black, new PointF(0, 0));
}
```

Comment: .. which you use as a basis, because there will be necessary some iteration (based on either simple rule, like decrease by 0.1 or by more complicated, to example, dividing by half of previous size, if it fits - try to increase, etc) and perhaps some logic what can split text in rows before `MeasureStringMin` (if text can be shown in multiple lines).

Comment: This is the opposite of what the OP was asking for. They're looking to fit the font size to a rectangle, not a rectangle to a font size.

Answer (score 20):

It's been a while but I came across this issue.
MSDN offers a sample with a GetAdjustedFont method to help with this process:

*(shamelessly stolen from [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb986765.aspx)](https://web.archive.org/web/20150110030457/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb986765.aspx)*

```
public Font GetAdjustedFont(Graphics g, string graphicString, Font originalFont, int containerWidth, int maxFontSize, int minFontSize, bool smallestOnFail)
{
   Font testFont = null;
   // We utilize MeasureString which we get via a control instance           
   for (int adjustedSize = maxFontSize; adjustedSize >= minFontSize; adjustedSize--)
   {
      testFont = new Font(originalFont.Name, adjustedSize, originalFont.Style);

      // Test the string with the new size
      SizeF adjustedSizeNew = g.MeasureString(graphicString, testFont);

      if (containerWidth > Convert.ToInt32(adjustedSizeNew.Width))
      {
         // Good font, return it
         return testFont;
      }
   }

   // If you get here there was no fontsize that worked
   // return minimumSize or original?
   if (smallestOnFail)
   {
      return testFont;
   }
   else
   {
      return originalFont;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can measure the string width with whatever font size (e.g. 16), and then you can calculate your desired font size like this:

```
fontSize = (previouslyMeasuredFontSize * targetWidthOfString) / previouslyMeasuredStringWidth;
```

Answer (score 2):

I also needed something similar. I created some code to answer the need of drawing text inside a defined rectangle with several auto font size options (see DrawMethod enum). It also supports auto warp with and without auto font size. My solution was inspired by the answers above.
Be sure to add WindowsBase and PresentationCore assemblies.

**DrawTextToBitmap.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ReportPrepare
{
    class TextDrawing
    {
        public enum DrawMethod
        {
            AutosizeAccordingToText, // create the smallest bitmap needed to draw the text without word warp
            AutoFitInConstantRectangleWithoutWarp, // draw text with the biggest font possible while not exceeding rectangle dimensions, without word warp
            AutoWarpInConstantRectangle, // draw text in rectangle while performing word warp. font size is a constant input. drawing may exceed bitmap rectangle.
            AutoFitInConstantRectangleWithWarp // draw text with the biggest font possible while not exceeding rectangle dimensions, with word warp
        }

        private static void SetGraphicsHighQualityForTextRendering(Graphics g)
        {
            // The smoothing mode specifies whether lines, curves, and the edges of filled areas use smoothing (also called antialiasing). One exception is that path gradient brushes do not obey the smoothing mode. Areas filled using a PathGradientBrush are rendered the same way (aliased) regardless of the SmoothingMode property.
            g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

            // The interpolation mode determines how intermediate values between two endpoints are calculated.
            g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

            // Use this property to specify either higher quality, slower rendering, or lower quality, faster rendering of the contents of this Graphics object.
            g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

            // This one is important
            g.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;
        }

        public static Size MeasureDrawTextBitmapSize(string text, Font font)
        {
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(1, 1);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {
                SizeF size = g.MeasureString(text, font);
                return new Size((int)(Math.Ceiling(size.Width)), (int)(Math.Ceiling(size.Height)));
            }

        }

        public static int GetMaximumFontSizeFitInRectangle(string text, Font font, RectangleF rectanglef, bool isWarp, int MinumumFontSize=6, int MaximumFontSize=1000)
        {
            Font newFont;
            Rectangle rect = Rectangle.Ceiling(rectanglef);

            for (int newFontSize = MinumumFontSize; ; newFontSize++)
            {
                newFont = new Font(font.FontFamily, newFontSize, font.Style);

                List<string> ls = WarpText(text, newFont, rect.Width);

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                if (isWarp)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < ls.Count; ++i)
                    {
                        sb.Append(ls[i] + Environment.NewLine);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.Append(text);
                }

                Size size = MeasureDrawTextBitmapSize(sb.ToString(), newFont);
                if (size.Width > rectanglef.Width || size.Height > rectanglef.Height)
                {
                    return (newFontSize - 1);
                }
                if (newFontSize >= MaximumFontSize)
                {
                    return (newFontSize - 1);
                }

            }

        }

        public static List<string> WarpText(string text, Font font, int lineWidthInPixels)
        {
            string[] originalLines = text.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.None);

            List<string> wrappedLines = new List<string>();

            StringBuilder actualLine = new StringBuilder();
            double actualWidthInPixels = 0;

            foreach (string str in originalLines)
            {
                Size size = MeasureDrawTextBitmapSize(str, font);

                actualLine.Append(str + " ");
                actualWidthInPixels += size.Width;

                if (actualWidthInPixels > lineWidthInPixels)
                {
                    actualLine =  actualLine.Remove(actualLine.ToString().Length - str.Length - 1, str.Length);
                    wrappedLines.Add(actualLine.ToString());
                    actualLine.Clear();
                    actualLine.Append(str + " ");
                    actualWidthInPixels = size.Width;
                }
            }

            if (actualLine.Length > 0)
            {
                wrappedLines.Add(actualLine.ToString());
            }

            return wrappedLines;
        }

        public static Bitmap DrawTextToBitmap(string text, Font font, Color color, DrawMethod mode, RectangleF rectanglef)
        {
            StringFormat drawFormat = new StringFormat();
            Bitmap bmp;
            switch (mode)
            {
                case DrawMethod.AutosizeAccordingToText:
                    {
                        Size size = MeasureDrawTextBitmapSize(text, font);

                        if (size.Width == 0 || size.Height == 0)
                        {
                            bmp = new Bitmap(1, 1);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            bmp = new Bitmap(size.Width, size.Height);
                        }

                        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
                        {
                            SetGraphicsHighQualityForTextRendering(g);

                            g.DrawString(text, font, new SolidBrush(color), 0, 0);

                            return bmp;
                        }

                    }
                case DrawMethod.AutoWarpInConstantRectangle:
                    {
                        Rectangle rect =  Rectangle.Ceiling(rectanglef);
                        bmp = new Bitmap(rect.Width,rect.Height);

                        if (rect.Width == 0 || rect.Height == 0)
                        {
                            bmp = new Bitmap(1, 1);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            bmp = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height);
                        }

                        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
                        {
                            SetGraphicsHighQualityForTextRendering(g);

                            g.DrawString(text, font, new SolidBrush(color), rectanglef, drawFormat);

                            return bmp;
                        }

                    }
                case DrawMethod.AutoFitInConstantRectangleWithoutWarp:
                    {
                        Rectangle rect = Rectangle.Ceiling(rectanglef);

                        bmp = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height);

                        if (rect.Width == 0 || rect.Height == 0)
                        {
                            bmp = new Bitmap(1, 1);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            bmp = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height);
                        }

                        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
                        {
                            int fontSize = GetMaximumFontSizeFitInRectangle(text, font, rectanglef, false);

                            SetGraphicsHighQualityForTextRendering(g);

                            g.DrawString(text, new Font(font.FontFamily, fontSize,font.Style, GraphicsUnit.Point), new SolidBrush(color), rectanglef, drawFormat);


                            return bmp;
                        }

                    }
                case DrawMethod.AutoFitInConstantRectangleWithWarp:
                    {
                        Rectangle rect = Rectangle.Ceiling(rectanglef);

                        if (rect.Width == 0 || rect.Height == 0)
                        {
                            bmp = new Bitmap(1, 1);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            bmp = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height);
                        }

                        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
                        {
                            int fontSize = GetMaximumFontSizeFitInRectangle(text, font, rectanglef, true);

                            SetGraphicsHighQualityForTextRendering(g);

                            g.DrawString(text, new Font(font.FontFamily, fontSize, font.Style, GraphicsUnit.Point), new SolidBrush(color), rectanglef, drawFormat);


                            return bmp;
                        }

                    }
            }
            return null;

        }



    }
}
```

**Usage Example:
Form1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


// add WindowsBase and PresentationCore assemblies

namespace ReportPrepare
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        PictureBox picbox = new PictureBox();
        int i = 0;
        Timer t = new Timer();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            this.Controls.Add(picbox);
            picbox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

            t.Interval = 5000;
            t.Tick += t_Tick;
            t.Enabled = true;

            this.Shown += Form1_Shown;
            this.SizeChanged += Form1_SizeChanged;

            this.Size = new Size(812, 400);

            this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

        }

        void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DrawText();
        }

        void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            i++;
            if (i > 3)
            {
                i = 0;
            }
            DrawText();
        }


        private void DrawText()
        {

            // text and font
            string text = "one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve";

            Font font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 30, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point);

            switch (i)
            {
                case 0:
                    picbox.Image = TextDrawing.DrawTextToBitmap(text, font, Color.Red, TextDrawing.DrawMethod.AutosizeAccordingToText, new RectangleF(0, 0, picbox.Width, picbox.Height));
                    break;
                case 1:
                    picbox.Image = TextDrawing.DrawTextToBitmap(text, font, Color.Red, TextDrawing.DrawMethod.AutoFitInConstantRectangleWithoutWarp, new RectangleF(0, 0, picbox.Width, picbox.Height));
                    break;
                case 2:
                    picbox.Image = TextDrawing.DrawTextToBitmap(text, font, Color.Red, TextDrawing.DrawMethod.AutoWarpInConstantRectangle, new RectangleF(0, 0, picbox.Width, picbox.Height));
                    break;
                case 3:
                    picbox.Image = TextDrawing.DrawTextToBitmap(text, font, Color.Red, TextDrawing.DrawMethod.AutoFitInConstantRectangleWithWarp, new RectangleF(0, 0, picbox.Width, picbox.Height));
                    break;
            }
            this.Text = ((TextDrawing.DrawMethod)(i)).ToString() + "                      Please resize window size by mouse to see drawing methods differences";

        }

        private void Form1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            t.Enabled = false;
            t.Enabled = true;
            DrawText();
        }





    }
}
```

The example toggles between drawing modes automatically once every 5 seconds. The picturebox is docked inside main form. Resizing of the form shows the user the difference between the drawing modes.

Comment: You're unnecessarily creating a temporary Bitmap object and Graphics object every time you measure the string.  Instead, create one of each, perform your iterative measurements, then dispose them.