# How to change dynamically font size so the volume of text suites to rectangle size?

Tags: c#, fonts

I write an application that enables me to collect a medical history about a patient. The problem is I wrote a code that enables me to put the text into the rectangle but when the volume of text is bigger than width and height it doesn't fit to rectangle size.

[image]

The question is how to dynamically make the font smaller when the volume of text is bigger then the rectangle size?
The code:

```cs
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    using (Font font1 = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point))
    {
        RectangleF rectF1 = new RectangleF(30, 30, 780, 200);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(richTextBox2.Text, font1, Brushes.Black, rectF1);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, Rectangle.Round(rectF1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not make the rectangle larger or add a scrollbar? Making the font size smaller sounds like it's gonna make it hard to read.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Auto Resize Font to fit rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15571715/auto-resize-font-to-fit-rectangle)

Comment: Because I want to do this way that the font makes smaller And I want to print the document after I wrote the data into richtextbox and with scrollbars won't work

Comment: It's not the answer I tried it but the code makes rectangle fit to string and I want the way around

Comment: On contrary, the code calculates the font size to fit the rectangle.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30567857/669576) in the linked question suggests trying different fonts until you find one that fits.

Comment: You can measure the Text, compare with the bounding rectangles where the Text must fit, then [apply a transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.transform) to the Graphics object [based on the scale](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.matrix.scale) you have determined.

Comment: @Jimi With a smaller font, the text will have the same width but smaller height, with line breaks in different places. With transformations you will get ugly vertically squished text with line breaks in the same places.

Comment: @GSerg It depends on how it's applied. E.g., this calculates the Text scale based on the size of a Control: [Scale Label text in line with Label size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52993233/7444103). -- I assume the OP has a small amount of text to fit into the bounds of that rectangle, it cannot for sure be an undetermined amount of text, since the Font size may get so small that makes the text completely unreadable. So, if a simple scale is applied to text that barely fits, you won't notice it even if the calculation is very simple. Otherwise, the calculation becomes slightly more complex.

Comment: But how to rewrite this code not to change rectangle's size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, one option is to just keep trying smaller and smaller fonts until you find one that fits. This is not super efficient, but if it is not done often, it works.

```
// Try to find a font size that fits
int GetFontSize(string text, Graphics graphics, RectangleF rect, string fontName, int maxFontSize=32)
{
    while (maxFontSize > 6)
    {
        using (var font = new Font(fontName, maxFontSize))
        {
            var calc = graphics.MeasureString(text, font, (int)rect.Width, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
            if (calc.Height <= rect.Height)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        maxFontSize -= 1;
    }
    return maxFontSize;
}
```

Sample usage:

```
// Helper function to draw a string and rectangle
void DrawText(Graphics graphics, string text, RectangleF rect, string fontName="Arial")
{
    int fontSize = GetFontSize(text, graphics, rect, fontName);
    using(var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black))
    using(var pen = new Pen(brush))
    using (var font = new Font(fontName, fontSize))
    {
        graphics.DrawString(text, font, brush, rect, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
        graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rect.X, rect.Y, rect.Width, rect.Height);
    }
}

// Test cases
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    string text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";
    RectangleF[] testCases = {
        new RectangleF(10, 10, 300, 100),
        new RectangleF(10, 120, 600, 200),
        new RectangleF(10, 330, 60, 400),
        new RectangleF(10, 330, 60, 400),
        new RectangleF(80, 330, 400, 60)
    };
    foreach (var r in testCases) {
        DrawText(e.Graphics, text, r);
    }
}
```

Output from sample code:
[image]

Comment: This is what I was looking for many thanks to you !!!!