# How to make dynamically font smaller for many richtextboxes

Tags: c#

I've got question to this post
[How to change dynamically font size so the volume of text suites to rectangle size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68215860/how-to-change-dynamically-font-size-so-the-volume-of-text-suites-to-rectangle-si).
I changed the content of string variable from simple text to richtextbox.text. But the question is how to use those functions to multiple separate richtextboxes? When I try to add parameters to int and void functions it doest work. This code works for one string variable but how to rewrite it for more string separate variables?
I want:

```
    string text1 = richtextbox1.Text
    string text2 = richtextbox2.Text
    .....
```

Comment: I usually use `Graphics.MeasureString`. look at the width, resize until it fits

Answer (score -1):

First of all, if it uses a text box, select it. Click on the arrow at the top of the line and check the option that appears, and then you can make it bigger and smaller in all directions. If you use a label, select it in the section. Properties Go down, unlock the size from yes to no, and after the size section, make it smaller or larger, and if you want to enlarge or reduce the text of the text, click on the label or text box where the text is and From the properties section, go to the font section, click on it, click on the three dots, then select the desired font and size, then click on the ok button.
I hope I was able to help